# git showing duplicate commits in log and rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I messed up my `fix-ad-failures` branch somehow while rebasing against my `dev` branch and now have duplicate commits in my `git log`.  When I do a `git rebase -i HEAD~6`, I see the duplicates:

```
pick 086b514 BUG FIX [...]
pick 58ff4cd Write spec for ad controller
pick 8289cb5 Fix spec failures in ad model
pick 618e995 Write spec for ad controller
pick d8f0bbc Fix spec failures in ad model
pick 7cd0682 Refactor ad view [...]
```

The first commit here (`086b514`) is from my `dev` branch.  The rest were made on `fix-ad-failures`.

What is the proper way to get rid of these duplicates and properly rebase against my `dev` branch?

Answer (score 0):

as you already do rebase interactive, just rearrange commits and squash duplicates, I guess:

```
pick 58ff4cd Write spec for ad controller
f 618e995 Write spec for ad controller
pick 8289cb5 Fix spec failures in ad model
f d8f0bbc Fix spec failures in ad model
```